# Slow Scrolling of recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am fetching Large json data from server using retrofit and I used pagination in fetching these data, now I used EndlessScrollView to my recyclerview
the problem is when I am scrolling the recyclerview, it is so slow

Comment: use [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) google's support library

Comment: it is very slow also

Comment: no, it is not: *"The paging library makes it easier for your app to gradually load information as needed from a data source, without overloading the device or waiting too long for a big database query.

"*

Comment: I know, it is load the data but the scroll is very slow

Comment: then do not use any "EndlessScrollView" - use normal `RecyclerView` instead

Comment: you have any idea of how to use normal recycler view as infinite scrolable with pagination ?

Comment: yes, i said that in my first comment above - read about `PagedListAdapter` and `LivePagedListBuilder` [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html#classes)

Answer (score 0):

If your recyclerview is contained within a scrollview, try: `myRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Comment: are you using any logic on your onBindViewHolder?

Answer (score 0):

Make the request to server page by page.
when you reach to the bottom of `RecyclerView`, make the request for next page.